# Access GridGroupHeaderItem from GridDataItem

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

How do i access a `GridGroupHeaderItem` from a `GridDataItem`, as in here is my code:

```
foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in _gridFilterQuestionAnswer.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Item))
{
    // Code to access the GridGroupHeaderItem
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not access `GridGroupHeaderItem` from a `GridDataItem`. Only reverse is possible.

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
foreach (GridGroupHeaderItem groupHeader in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.GroupHeader))
{
    GridItem[] children = groupHeader.GetChildItems();
    foreach (GridDataItem child in children)
    {
        GridDataItem childItem = child as GridDataItem;
        //condition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is:

```
.GetItems(GridItemType.Item)
```

[GridItemType](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/t_telerik_web_ui_griditemtype.html) supports GroupHeader, so use:

```
.GetItems(GridItemType.GroupHeader)
```

And it will be returned.